# Text delay in Firefox 4

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

This is a very small issue; in Firefox 4, there is a small but noticeable delay between page layout and the text showing up. This delay does not exist in Firefox 3.

This could be a Firefox 4 issue though.

Also, the DroidSans @font-face does not seem to be used in Firefox 4, even though the browser supports @font-face.

Comment: We're looking into this. Meanwhile, I recommend downloading the Droid Sans fonts: http://www.google.com/webfonts/family?family=Droid+Sans#download

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Custom font support required changes to HTTP headers for support in FF.  This will be fixed after our next deploy.

Comment: Ah, I see, Firefox has cross-domain restriction...